# How to make PPA build for particular release

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad

I'm creating my first proper PPA to patch a problem with Compiz. debbuild/dput works fine but Launchpad tells me it's only building it for Quantal.

I've no interest in doing that for the minute - I'd like it to build for Precise. What do I need to do to get this done?

Edit: I went into the package page in Launchpad and managed to copy the package I uploaded for another release, but is there a way of setting the default release(s) for a PPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would surmise from your question that your `debian/changelog` file has defaulted to `quantal` instead of `precise` for the target.

For example - this is an example changelog for a PPA package I have recently built:

```
rhythmbox-plugin-albumartsearch (0.1-3) precise; urgency=low

  * folder rename

 -- fossfreedom <fossfreedom@somewheremail.com>  Thur, 07 Jun 2012 13:19:18 +0100
```

You'll note - the target is `precise`

If you use `dch -i` to create your change log then this will not only increment your version number but change to the next development release.

Best use `dch -i --distribution [foo]` to ensure that the changelog is created correctly for the distro you wish to use - where `[foo]` is `precise` in your example.

---

Useful link:

- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide

Comment: Yup, I used `dch -i` and didn't notice. Doh, and thanks!